# Fetching data from DB via Kafka Connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it’s possible to query data on demand from a DB (e.g. Mongo DB) via Kafka connectors?

i.e. let’s say I have a collection of cars with the following data –

```
{
       Brand: Mahindra,
       Model: XUV300
}
{
       Brand: Mahindra,
       Model: XUV500
}
{
       Brand: TATA,
       Model: Nexon
}
```

I want to fetch all Mahindra Models via Kafka connector.
What should I do so I can query and get this data in one of my Kafka topics?

The aim is to control everything via Kafka and not to interact directly with db via code.
Tried going through Kafka doc and Google but didn't find any solutions

Answer (score 1):

Some connectors do allow custom filters queries, such as the JDBC source.

Otherwise, you can try to use the Filter SMT with a predicate to filter data that's part of the record

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html